# Is there a method for polymorphic associate to non mongoid document?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid, polymorphic-associations

I have an Order class with orderalbe field that is polymorphic. Some products associate with Order, for example Book.

It works fine if Book is Mongoid::Document, but some products not store in local database instead of from API fetching.

Is there a good way to handle this case? Should I implements some methods that can be same as local store?

```rb
  class Order
    include Mongoid::Document
    belongs_to :orderable, polymorphic: true
  end

  class Book
    include Mongoid::Document
  end

  class Car
    def self.find(id)
      # Fetch from API
      new Car()
    end
  end
```

```rb
o = Order.create(orderable_id: 1, orderable_type: 'Car')
o.orderable
=> nil  # why is nil? Not use self.find() method?
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer by looking at the source code of mongoid. If other people have similar needs, I hope some help. Please let me know if there is a better solution.

I looked at the source code of mongoid and found it was actually queried by the where statement（not find method).

```rb
class Car
  def self.where(*args)
    # Fetch from API
    [new(fetched_attributes_by_api)]
  end
end

o = Order.first
o.orderable
=> #<Car _id: 1>
```